# Search my videos by Tag

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I can't find specification about search my videos.

I'm creating API calls to vimeo for one client, and I need to search videos by tag, or tags.

I've tried this

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?access_token=xxxx&tags=xxxx
```

and

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?access_token=xxxx&tag=xxxx
```

and I always receive full list of videos.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the API.
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/tags#/{word}/videos

Comment: Single user app, and I want to filter my videos.

Comment: We eventually plan on supporting tag filters across all endpoints, but it's not available yet.